# A question on filter order and gain

Tags: active-filter

As far as I understand, "filter order" is the number of poles or roughly the number of capacitors in an active filter. The higher the order the sharper the roll off.

I'm trying to make a second order Bessel filter with a gain of 500 but what is meant by "stage gain"?

More importantly I wonder what is the relation between an active filter being unity gain and "filter order"?

What I mean is that: If I want to both filter and have gain should I forget about 2nd order and higher filter? As far as I saw in examples an active filter can only provide gain only if it is 1st order. 2nd order and higher order active filters are very good for filtering but they don't provide gain they are unity gain filters(?). Is this correct?

edit:

[image]

edit[image] 2:

Comment: No, 2nd order sections can have gain too. It's just that the unity gain ones (Sallen&Key) are easiest to find design info for. Simply increasing the gain of a unity gain 2nd order section will also change its Q, so there's a bit more to getting them right. Try it in a simulator.

Comment: How abut finding a unity gain 3rd order Sallen&Key and amplifying the output with another opamp? Is that a common practice?

Comment: @user134429 "common practice" in filter design is ... a slippery slope. You need a filter with high gain, so you're out of the area of "common practice", and, as Brian said, you should extensively simulate a few design approaches with models of real opamps and real passives to figure out what works best for *your* specific use case. Sorry, no general advice for a special case :)

Comment: That works, but for a little more work you can have a simpler circuit - usually a win.

Comment: @user134429 for a "getting a starting point" problem, you might want to try Analog.com 's "filter design wizard", which imho is pretty nice.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I tried that tool now. But when I set the roll off as 20Hz it only works for 1st order filters. Second order Bessel filter with 20Hz cut off not possible?

Comment: Second order has no to little benefit then (f_stop ~= 2· f_passbandedge). If you want to try: reduce the passband ripple from 3dB to let's say 1dB. Increas stopband attenuation. Make sharper transition.

Comment: @user134429 or, actually, try setting 27 dB of gain. That should select an active filter automagically.

Comment: @MarcusMüller see my edit 2; it does not select 2nd order filter.

Comment: @user134429 does something different for me; did you disable JavaScript or something? https://i.imgur.com/43wePkW.png

Comment: @MarcusMüller Im after 20Hz not 20kHz. Yours is 20kHz

Comment: something to do with stop band?

Comment: Ah, right. That filter is simply too "relaxed" in transition width (much larger than passband) for multi-stage to make sense. Use an amplifier and filter separately.

Comment: (Are you *sure*? That filter specification seems kind of senseless)

Comment: My aim is to average 8mV 490Hz PWM signals to constant DC with an okay response time and range from 0 to 4V. All the simulations I tried failed. I would be glad to have your opinion.

Comment: I opened a new question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/301520/trouble-with-converting-pwm-to-analog

Answer (score 1):

Any gain that you get in a filter is incidental to its operation. A passive LC filter will have nearly unity gain, a single Sallen Key filter stage will have gain somewhere between 1 and 3 depending on how you configure it.

Design your filter, find out what gain it has, and make up the balance with an amplifier. Noise and signal level issues will determine whether you put the amplifier before or after, or even split it before and after.

You can add capacitors to amplifiers to shape the gain, but anything more than single order sections quickly becomes 'design the filter, and design the gain'.