# Trouble with converting PWM to analog

Tags: active-filter

I'm trying to average 8mV 490Hz PWM signals to analog voltage. I could do it with a passive RC filter, but I want to use an active filter and gain with an okay response time.

So the PWM freq. is 490Hz.

Pulses are 0...8mV.

The PWM average will go to a MCU pin to be read so the range after gain should not exceed 5V.

I have been trying tools and filters in simulations and all failed until now.

What should be the approach to design a simple active filter topology here.

Answer (score 2):

TI has a better Filter App for this then you can choose Elliptical, Cauer, Butterworth , exact values or 0.5%' 1% etc.

You must learn to define specs first, pass band gain , cutoff f, passband ripple, band reject f and attenuation before starting any design.

So define your gain and PWM attenuation then it will compute order of filter needed. Then menu> edit > design and start again until happy.

### added

What you need to learn is how rise speeds up with more BW using higher order filters not simple ones. It's not hard with TI filter design app.

All digital telephony needs a brick wall 4kHz LPF to sample at 8kHz and fit at least 3.5kHz using single IC filter chips that are 7th order.

You have many choics; but not a simple RC solution, yet not that hard! Again only YOU can define the specs.

Decide what latency you can live with at 490Hz (slow) PWM ?1ms, 2,4,8,16,32,64,128 ms ? and not 1second then how much accuracy 10%,2% etc.

This determines the optimum solution.

Common to all solutions is convert 8mVpp pulse to logic levels thus gain <1000, while all inverting CMOS logic gates (except non-buffered) have a DC gain of 1000+ so to get logic levels it is as simple as C coupled to INV input and R feedback using ~RC >10/f to get good square wave or narrow pulse, as long as PWM traces don't have noise glitches. you will get full swing from 0 to Vdd.

1) the fastest PWM to DC converter takes one (1) cycle of latency . this is done with an integrate that dumps the charge cap using a precision Vdd/2 Vref on Vin(+) and a CMOS analog switch with a small NPO cap.

2) the next approach is a steep high order LPF at 250Hz with ripple at 490Hz TBD?? this has latency of ~<0.5/250Hz

3) the worst design is 50xT simple RC filter

Comment: One of my problem is the logic need to be followed for a given PWM what cutoff freq. I need. For example PWM to be averaged to analog is 490Hz. For 490Hz and less than 1% ripple I want the filter time constant to be a least 50 times the pulse period of 2ms or at least 100ms, giving a low-pass corner frequency of 1.6Hz. Is that correct? But when I increase the time-constant, the response time slows down. I dont know where to start and cannot find a step by step example o the issue.

Comment: define rise time as T=0.35/f. , this your cutoff and then gain then attenuation of 490Hz.  .. use the TI filter App. you can choose anything but closer to 490Hz than he higher the order filter but then less group delay. order is defined by number of caps with 6dB/ octave per order

Comment: The signal will be 8mV DC at 100% duty cycle after the filter or 4mV DC at 50% duty cycle after the filter. The question is should I first active filter(means average this 8mV PWM) and then amplify it OR should I first amplify the 8mV PWM and then apply the active filter? Or it doesn't matter the order? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your 8mV signal is a PWM signal then you don't need to use a linear amplifier.  You can use a comparator device to transform the 8mV to 5V TTL (or whatever logic voltage you are using).  The 5V TTL signal can then be averaged using a simple RC filter.  If the RC filter needs to drive a load then follow it with a simple analog buffer amp.

Comment: 8mV amplitude may vary with temperature o the load resistance it is not 100% constant. Im measuring current so the 8mV peak is from the sensing resistor.

Comment: If the amplitude of PWM signal varies than you are doing it wrong. The amplitude has to be stable to get meaningful results. The comparator device is a very good solution to your problem.